# IntelliJ - cannot connect to postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, intellij-14, goland

Inside Intellij (Goland to be precise) I have configured two database connections - one to postgres 12.10, another to 12.8. Both have worked perfectly up until 30 minutes ago.

The 12.8 connection, when trying to do anything with it, communicates this error:

```
DBMS: 
Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=exact
Driver:  (ver. , JDBC)
Effective version: PostgreSQL (ver. 0.0)
[XX000] FATAL: type 700 not supported as catcache key.
```

I have tried looking up this problem but the Internet has *absolutely nothing* to offer on it.

I would like to hear any ideas on how to if not solve, but sidestep this problem. I have tried removing the connection and creating a new one, identical to the deleted one. Didn't help.

Comment: It looks like a PostgreSQL issue, that's where the error message comes from. (catcache.c that is) Is this server still running? Some cache issues have been fixed in 12.9 and 12.10, but there is already version 12.12. Check your server, make a backup and start patching.

Comment: Look in the db server's log file.